# Propel archivable behavior doesn't work properly (archived_at column doesn't get updated on insert)

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have some problems with the Propel's archivable behavior. For some reasons, Propel doesn't set archived_at field to the current datetime when the object is being archived.

My schema:

```
SeminarCustomer:
  tableName:          seminar_customer
  columns:
    id:              { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, foreignClass: Customer, foreignReference: id, onDelete: cascade }
    ...
    office_id:       { type: integer, required: false, foreignTable: office, foreignReference: id }
    entity_id:       { type: integer, required: true, default: 1 }
  propel_behaviors:
    timestampable:   ~
    archivable:      ~
```

SeminarCustomer::archive method:

```
public function archive(PropelPDO $con = null)
{
    if ($this->isNew()) {
        throw new PropelException('New objects cannot be archived. You must save the current object before calling archive().');
    }
    if (!$archive = $this->getArchive($con)) {
        $archive = new SeminarCustomerArchive();
        $archive->setPrimaryKey($this->getPrimaryKey());
    }
    $this->copyInto($archive, $deepCopy = false, $makeNew = false);
            // NOTE: here should be $archive->setArchivedAt(time());
    $archive->save($con);

    return $archive;
}
```

archived_at column definitely exists in my seminar_customer_archive table.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong ? Or maybe there is an error in the schema?

- Symfony: 1.4.17-DEV
- Propel: 1.6.3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you force the `log_archived_at` parameter of the Archivable behavior? It should work out of the box...

If it can helps, here is the documentation: http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/archivable.html

EDIT: Fixed by [PR #310](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/pull/310)

Comment: It should work, but ... It seems I've found a bug in Propel. I found a solution also. Now I am going to write some unit tests to test my bugfix.

Comment: Thank you! I'll review your PR then ;)